# Focusing on a textarea after dynamically editing textarea text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a textarea and everytime a 'keyup' is detected it sets the current value of the textarea to the textareas text. Reason is, so that this text becomes a part of the HTML and I can then use localStorage to save the inputted text.

my code so far...

```
$(document).on('keyup', '.note_text', function () {
    var text = $(this).val();
    $(this).text(text);
});
```

My issue is, as soon as the keyup is detected the text area is no longer in focus so you have to click back into it and type again, and obviously you can only hold keys down to continuously type, as if you type normally the function is triggered by the key up.

I'm using $(document) as the textarea is dynamically created into the DOM

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trial and error, I managed to find a working solution...

```
 $(document).on('keyup', '.className', function () {
    var text = $(this).val(); // Gets the text of the textarea being typed in
    $(this).html(text); // Set the text as part of the html of the textarea
    $(this).focus(); // refocuses back on the text area so the user can type
    save(); // saves the DOM to the localStorage
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Add this, as explained in the [jQuery documentation](https://api.jquery.com/focus/):

`$("textarea").trigger("focus");`

Which would be the same as the following without jQuery:

`document.querySelector('textarea').focus();`

Both of these examples are assuming that your html only contains one textarea. Otherwise you'd have to add logic to select the correct one.

Comment: I have more than one textarea. Is the logic complex? I've added a counter variable that increments by 1 everytime a new text area is added, and that number is set at the text areas 'id', eg. if there are three textareas added, they'd be id='1' id='2', id='3'. And so on and so forth if more were added.

Comment: You can get all the textareas on the page as an array, and then get the relevant one by indexing into the array. For example, to get the 3rd textarea: `document.querySelectorAll("textarea")[2]`